# Compiling single APK - OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt

Anyone knows the procedure to create a single APK file that includes source available at http://code.google.com/p/zapwireless/source/browse/?r=2#svn%2Ftrunk and http://code.google.com/p/zapwireless/source/browse/trunk/Makefile?r=2

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have the source, I would put it into the feeds/packages/{category} directory into one of the categories. Then run 'make feeds/packages/{category}/{your-package}' and it should create it.